# JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My code isnt working and I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementByTagName' of null at HTMLButtonElement.countInParagraphs at line 76. 
can you help me figure out my problem. 
Im thinking new eyes can figure out the problem better than I can. 
Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Word Count Version 2</title>
        <style>
            button{
                margin: 1em;
            }
            #leftArea{
                width: 35%;
                float: left;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: #C200AF;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #rightArea{
                width: 30%;
                float: left;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: #C2AF00;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #midArea{
                width: 30%;
                float: left;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: #00C2AF;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            h3{
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            #paragraphs > p{
                background-color: #66ffff;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            "use strict;"

        function buildParagraphs()
        {
            var sentenceArea = document.getElementById("sentence");
            var words = sentenceArea.value;
            if(words.length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            var wordsArray = words.split(" ");

            //Get the div element with id = paragraphs and assign it to a variable called midDiv
            var midDiv = document.getElementById("paragraphs");
            for(var i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++)
            {
                //Build the p elements
                //create a new p element and store it in a variable called newPara
                var newPara = document.createElement("p");
                //create a new text node from the current item in the wordsArray and store it in a variable called textNode
                var textNode = document.createTextNode(wordsArray[i]);
                //Append the text node to the newPara you just created
                newPara.appendChild(textNode);
                //Append the newPara element to the midDiv element
                midDiv.appendChild(newPara);
            }

            sentenceArea.value = "";

        }

        function countInParagraphs()
        {
            var textArea = document.getElementById("searchWord");
            var searchWord = textArea.value;
            //Get the div element with id = paragraphs and assign it to a variable called midDiv
            var midDiv = document.getElementById("wordList");
            //Declare a variable called paraElements and assign all of the paragraph (p) tags from the midDiv element to it.
    ---> LINE 76        var paraElements = midDiv.getElementsByTagName("p");

            var count = 0;
            //Start a for-loop that sets a variable i to 0; checks it against the length of the paraElements array; and increments i by 1
            for (var i =0; i <paraElements.length; i++)
            {
                //Write an if-statement that checks the innerHTML of the current paragraph element
                if (searchWord == paraElements[i].innerHTML)
                {
                    count++
                }
                //against the searchWord variable to see if they are the same. If they are, add 1 to the count. 

            }//end for

            //Get the element with id = word and assign it to a variable called wordArea
            var wordArea = document.getElementById("word");
            //Assign the searchWord to the innerHTML of wordArea
            wordArea.innerHTML = searchWord;
            //Get the element with id = wordCount and assign it to a variable called countArea
            var countArea = document.getElementById("wordCount");
            //Assign the count to the innerHTML of countArea
            count.innerHTML = countArea;
            textArea.value = "";
        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
            var buildBtn = document.getElementById("buildBtn");
            buildBtn.onclick = buildParagraphs;
            var countBtn = document.getElementById("countBtn");
            countBtn.onclick = countInParagraphs;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "leftArea">
        <div>
        Enter a sentence: 
        <textarea id = "sentence" rows = "10" cols = "30"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button type="button" id = "buildBtn">Build paragraphs</button>
        </div>
        <div>
        Enter a word to find in the paragraphs: 
        <input type="text" id = "searchWord">
        </div>
        <div>
        <button type="button" id = "countBtn">Count in paragraphs</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "midArea">
        <h3>Word list</h3>
        <div id = "paragraphs">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "rightArea">
        The number of times the word '<span id = "word"></span>' turns up in the sentence is: <span id = "wordCount"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have no element with `id="wordList"`, so `midDiv` is `null` from the line before. You probably meant to use `"paragraphs"` rather than `"wordList"` (like in `buildParagraphs()`).

Comment: @nnnnnn Is correct, possibly misspelled `<span id = "word">`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your script to the end of your HTML document, right before `</body>` so that it looks like so: `<script>...</script></body>`.

I believe `null` means the element does not exist yet in the DOM, as opposed to `undefined` which means it's in the DOM, so it can be found, but is undefined.

If your script executes before the rest of your HTML document loads, you'll usually end up getting `null` and perhaps sometimes `undefined` errors.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no element with id 'wordList', this throws an error. But there is an element with id 'word'. So you can replace id to `var midDiv = document.getElementById("word");` in line number 74.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have the element with id == wordList at the page. But try to change string 76 to the code:

```
var paraElements = [];
if (midDiv) {
    paraElements = midDiv.getElementsByTagName("p");
}
```